# Jquery FadeIn and Out on Multiple Divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadein, fadeout

I'm usina script to fade div's in and out. It works fine on one but not not at all on the other one. Does anyone know why? Here is fiddle of it http://jsfiddle.net/MeEc6/

This is the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function()                         

    {  var book = $('#book');
       var synopsis = $('#synopsis');
function runIt() {
   synopsis.animate({opacity:'+=1'}, 1000);
   synopsis.animate({opacity:'-=0.9'}, 2000, runIt).delay(2000);
}
       runIt();});
```

Comment: Both animations are performed on the `synopsis` object. Did you want one performed on the `book` object?

Comment: yes. what would be the proper way to implemint that?

Comment: Java =/= JavaScript. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you're wanting to do the same animation on `book` and `synopsis`, but you're only including the `animate` method on `synopsis`:

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MeEc6/1/)

```
function runIt() {
   synopsis.animate({opacity:'+=1'}, 1000);
   synopsis.animate({opacity:'-=0.9'}, 2000, runIt).delay(2000);

   book.animate({opacity:'+=1'}, 1000);
   book.animate({opacity:'-=0.9'}, 2000, runIt).delay(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to both: http://jsfiddle.net/MeEc6/3/

```
<div id="synopsis" class="fader">
    <img src="http://www.unearthingfilm.com/images/interface/shine.png" width="150" height="150" />
</div>
<!-- End of Synopsis -->
<div id="book" class="fader">
    <img src="http://www.unearthingfilm.com/images/bookGlow.png" width="365" height="347" />
</div>
```

And animate that:

```
var synopsis = $('.fader');
```

Comment: thats great! would I have to re write the code if I wanted them to fade in random patterns rather than both at the same time?

Comment: Yup. Do what Chase suggests.

Comment: Ok. Thanks I will give it a go and let you guys know